# Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Today I tried (unsucessfully) to implent the [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)
in my app, the idea was to try to use them and fallback to a webview in case, but I am stuck to opening them: here is what I tried

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
        data: 'http://www.google.com',
        packageName: 'com.android.chrome'
    });
    intent.putExtra('android.support.customtabs.extra.SESSION', null);
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

What it does is simply opening the page on chrome (so, the same thing that I can do with Ti.Platform.openURL but only for android); am I missing something? Do someone know of a module/widget ala [Ti.safariDialog](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.safaridialog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implementation guide](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#implementationguide) uses `putBinder` where you use `putExtra` so I guess that's the issue. Titanium currently doesn't expose `putBinder` so you'd have to request that to be added in a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org)